# External component has thrown an exception while using Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have recently updated my SQL connection string to `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` and here is it:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Common;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Media;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;

    // connection for header file
    protected OleDbCommand headExcelConnection()
    {
        // Connect to the Excel Spreadsheet 
        string headConnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + "Data Source=" + Server.MapPath("~/imports/headerorder.xls") + ";" + "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

        OleDbConnection headXConn = new OleDbConnection(headConnStr);
        headXConn.Open();

        OleDbCommand headCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", headXConn);
        return headCommand;
        headXConn.Close();
    }
```

I am getting the following error at line `headXConn.Open()`;

> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException:
>   External component has thrown an exception.
>
> SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an
>   exception.]
>   System.Data.Common.IDBInitializeInitialize.Invoke(IntPtr pThis) +0
>   System.Data.OleDb.DataSourceWrapper.InitializeAndCreateSession(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, SessionWrapper& sessionWrapper) +304
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString
>   constr, OleDbConnection connection) +193
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool,
>   DbConnection owningObject) +86
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup) +29
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection) +4911420
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +117
>   System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open() +40
>   importsEmails.headExcelConnection() in importsEmails.aspx.cs:65
>   importsEmails.BtnViewHeader_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   importsEmails.aspx.cs:89
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: please remove the sql tag, not a sql question :)

Comment: Is your target CPU set to 32bit?  I know that library has trouble running 64bit

Comment: Hi Joe, This is on the webpage that is hosted with a hosting company, Sorry to ask like this but how would I know if this is set to 32bit. Thanks again

Comment: @niceoneishere check this [page](https://errorcodespro.com/fix-error-code-0x80004005-windows-7-10/) if you didn't yet. Maybe there is a missing update or something. this webpage worked before?, there is any change recently?